# installation of package ‘ggvis’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.5 and have R v.3.1.3 installed.

I'm using the command

```
install.packages("ggvis")
```

And that yields

```
ERROR: dependency ‘mime’ is not available for package ‘shiny’                                                                                                       
* removing ‘/home/milia/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/shiny’                              
ERROR: dependency ‘shiny’ is not available for package ‘ggvis’                              
* removing ‘/home/milia/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/ggvis’                          

The downloaded source packages are in                                                              
               ‘/tmp/Rtmp6Cz9En/downloaded_packages’                                             
Warning messages:                                                                         
1: In install.packages("ggvis") :                                                           
    installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status                                                                                                         
2: In install.packages("ggvis") :                                                           
    installation of package ‘ggvis’ had non-zero exit status
```

So I figured I had to install shiny first. So I typed

install.packages("shiny")

Which gave:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘mime’ is not available for package ‘shiny’                              
* removing ‘/home/milia/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/shiny’                                         

The downloaded source packages are in                                                             
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp6Cz9En/downloaded_packages’                                             
Warning message:                                                                          
In install.packages("shiny") :                                                            
   installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
```

So I thought installing mime.

Did as usual

```
install.packages("mime")
```

Which gave

```
Warning message:                                                                          
In install.packages("mime") :                                                             
  installation of package ‘mime’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm not sure what to do next, and the similar problems in stack with a non-zero exit status didn't help much.

My Rprofile can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/JQSx2kDW).

Comment: `install.packages("ggvis", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: By doing that I get 12 errors of the type "non-zero exit status" for the packages mime, memoise, evaluate, formatR, highr, caTools, markdown, shiny, lubridate, knitr, ggvis, rmarkdown.

Comment: You only get this "non-zero exit status" message?

Comment: This is all I get: http://pastebin.com/Shyb5p8C

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your R installation. It is said that R could not find function "write.table". But `write.table` is part of the "utils" package, which is a default package in R.

Comment: I see. I'll do a reinstallation of R then and see how it goes. I'll let you know if that fixes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74088/discussion-between-milia-and-pascal).

Comment: Did you try installing httr and memoise separately before installing devtools?

install.packages(c("httr", "memoise", "devtools"))   or  You could try using https://cran.rstudio.com 2 as a CRAN mirror.

install.packages("devtools", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")